# Unit testing an AngularJS controller method that takes form as parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a controller in which I have a save method that accepts a form.

```
ctrl.save = function(form) {
        if (!form.$valid) return;
    ...
}
```

This is very convenient for working with the form because I can easily access values and do certain things based on their validity, state, etc.

```
if(form.someField.$dirty) { ... }
```

I have developed a fair amount of code using this approach and haven't had any problems with it until considering unit testing. Is there a way that I can mock the form easily using some Angular mock object, or is this a poor approach? Part of the reason I care about having access to the form in the method is that this form has multiple parts and each part calls the server independently depending on their state. In other words, I don't call to update things that haven't changed. Bearing that in mind, is this a poor approach? What alternative approach might I take that allows me to unit test this save method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a great solution to this problem, but it seems to work and lets me mock the form without having to process all of the html independently.

```
beforeEach(function () {
        //Set up a mocked form
        formMock = {
            $valid: false,
            firstName: { $dirty: false, $viewValue: '' },
            lastName: { $dirty: false, $viewValue: '' },
            emailAddress: { $dirty: false, $viewValue: '' },
            password: { $dirty: false, $viewValue: '' },
            address: { $dirty: false, $viewValue: '' },
            city: { $dirty: false, $viewValue: '' },
            selectedState: { code: '' },
            zip: { $dirty: false, $viewValue: '' }
        };

    });
```

Then in my test, I simply pass this object to the method that's expecting a form.

```
it('should do the stuff', function() {
    ctrl.save(formMock);
    expect(mockedService.spiedMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

I realize this isn't exactly an angular mocked object, but it would seem that as long as you include the properties that your controller/service is expecting, you can set those values and change them prior to evaluating your test conditions.

```
it('should do the stuff', function() {
    formMock.firstName.$viewValue = 'Hello';
    ctrl.save(formMock);
    expect(mockedService.spiedMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

In my case, I'm testing conditions within the spied method that act on the values passed in, and I really only care that based on the conditions I provide, the spied method is, or isn't called.